# how to connect disconnect the camera device using getUserMedia and webRTC

Tags: webrtc

I am creating an audio/video and chat application using webRTC and Node.js. I need to mute and unmute the camera device. 
Presently, I am able to disconnect and the other party is not able to see me, but the problem I see is that it doesn't disconnect the camera. It still remains active and connected as I see the camera flash still on.

I need help how to disconnect when muted and connect it back when unmuted. I want the same feature as we see in skype video call.

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting your media, in your success callback function you have to keep your localstream in a variable. Then, when you want to stop your stream, you can do `localstream.stop();`

To start again, you can repeat to call your `getUserMedia()` method again.

Answer (score 0):

It varies a bit between Firefox and Chrome. These steps, in this order, work for me.

1) Set the `src` property on your video element to empty string `''`.

2) Make sure the `stop` method exists before calling it as a function. Firefox doesn't have it, and if you try to run it, your code will throw an error.

```
if (localStream && localStream.stop) {
  localStream.stop();
}
```

3) After you call cameraStream.stop() (or not), set `localStream = null`. (Maybe not actually necessary, but it couldn't hurt to let the object get garbage-collected. And when the user asks to start the camera up again, you can check against the variable to see if you need to clean up after the previous stream before starting a new one.)

Comment: Firefox has always supported mediastream.stop(); it's used in our test pages at mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing.  Also, you don't need to set src to '' before calling stop() (at least in Firefox); stop() (per the spec) should stop capturing regardless of what's holding a handle to it.  If you want to be sure it's been fully released, you need to null out any handles to it as mentioned.